# Selection sort algorithm in Rust

Tags: rust

I am just trying to use Rust so I will be thankful for all remarks and corrections:

```
fn selection_sort(array: &mut [i32]) {

    let mut min;

    for i in 0..array.len() {

        min = i;

        for j in (i+1)..array.len() {

            if array[j] < array[min] {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        let tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = tmp;
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut values = [ 5, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 6 ];
    println!("Hello, world! The value is {:?}", values);

    selection_sort(&mut values);
    println!("Hello, world! The value is {:?}", values);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `min_by_key` to find the minimum's index and the method `swap` defined in slices:

```
fn selection_sort(array: &mut [i32]) {
    let len = array.len();
    for i in 0..len {
        let min = (i..len).min_by_key(|x| array[*x])
                          .unwrap();
        array.swap(min, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. No newlines after an opening brace but before the code starts
2. Use spaces around binary operators like `+`.
3. Use [`swap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap). This prevents you from needing to make a copy/clone of the variable.
4. Declare variables in as small a scope as possible. There's no reason to declare `min` outside of the array.
5. I'd use more iterator methods like `enumerate` to avoid array indexing, which incurs a small penalty for out-of-bounds checking.

```
fn selection_sort(array: &mut [i32]) {
    for i in 0..array.len() {
        let min_idx = array[i..].iter()
            .enumerate()
            .min_by_key(|&(_, v)| v)
            .map(|(i, _)| i)
            .unwrap_or(0);

        array.swap(i, min_idx + i);
    }
}
```

As a follow-up, I'd challenge you to make this algorithm work with more than just `i32` types!